# What device can switch ON and OFF different pads independently?

Tags: arduino, switches, device

I am looking for a device, but I am not sure what I need: maybe you have ideas.
I have a power supply connected to 16 electrodes. What I need is a device (see picture) between the power supply and the electrodes that allows me to switch ON and OFF independently each connection to each electrode. The switching time may be different for each of them (between 10 and 100 ms).  The voltage needed is between 2 and 5 V.

How can I realize such a device?[image]

Comment: Caution: this site is for design questions. Purchasing questions get closed very quickly. You need to edit that bit out of your question. You also need to add in voltage and current requirements.

Comment: You want to control multiple signals.... The easiest way is with multiple switches. The better way is with a micro controller. For the switching times you've just added, a micro controller would be required. Possibly driving FETs or some kind of transistor if the currents are higher.

Comment: "ON" means DC voltage at electrode.  What does "OFF" mean?  Floating? or grounded? 0V?  Also how much current will pass through the switch?  And how are the switches controlled?  What timing is required?  How many µS from control signal to change at electrode?  Please provide a lot more detail.

Comment: astable multivibrators maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

Since this post already has an arduino tag I'm going to suggest that you use an [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) (e.g. [micro](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-micro)) as the brain of your device.
Why?

- very flexible
- has 20 i/o pins (can be switched on or off)
- switches in a matter of µs (should easily be fast enough)
- easy to learn
- open source
- rather cheap.

An active output has 5V but limited current. So if you want to use the signal to drive heavier loads (e.g. leds) you would also add something to your outputs that can handle higher currents.
There are many options and tutorials depending on your needs (transistors, driver-chips, FETs, Relais …).

---

As others mentioned there are many more options to consider (other MCUs, complex timer circuits…) but this seems to be a practical solution.